# Anatomy of a Porch.com SMS lead alert

Tags: hyperlink

I would like to design the SMS referral link for a lead alerts application. (So the pro would receive the SMS message on their device with a link to click through to the job request details.) I'd like to make it secure and scalable. The link below arrives in the SMS as a shortened URL. That much I understand.

Porch.com does something similar and I'd like to know what the strategy is behind each segment in the URL (or your best estimation). Can someone help me understand?

Here is an example: (Thanks Porch.com)

https://porch.com/pro/project/3fd55669-d7cf-4655-892e-252080c34a79?c=50145918&email=12345@yahoo.com&referrerSource=sms

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First of all, this isn't really a question for Stack Overflow. This is a place for asking questions about code that doesn't work in order to get it to work.

Having said that, the more I looked at the URL as I was commenting on this question, the more I feel I worked out. This is my idea of what the URL is saying.

Here's the URL again: https://porch.com/pro/project/3fd55669-d7cf-4655-892e-252080c34a79?c=50145918&email=12345@yahoo.com&referrerSource=sms

The random string in the URL, `3fd55669-d7cf-4655-892e-252080c34a79`, looks like it is the identifier for the project itself. It's long and random, like a uuid, so it would be hard to guess, but can uniquely identify the project.

The `email` is presumably the email address of the pro that the SMS was sent to, so that the return on sending SMS projects to them can be measured.

The `referrerSource` is then used to measure how each of their referring sources is performing.

The only parameter that is impossible to really guess at is the `c`. Removing it (in fact, removing any or all of the query parameters) didn't change the result of loading the page. This implies that it is just another tracking parameter.

Hope that helps.